# How to receive the EmailTemplate Images in Email?

Tags: email-template

This is my custom text template code,i load the image in Documents and copy the image url and paste in src.But i didnt receive the images in my email ,just it shows text only........How to solve this?

```
 <img src=”https://na5.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01570000001G1nR&oid=00D70000000XXXX” alt=”My test image” height=”179” width=”702“/>
```

Comment: Do you have the "Externally Available Image" ticked on the image document?

Comment: Yes ,i enable the checkbox(Externally Available Image)

Answer (score 2):

Your URL looks different from what I'd expect. Double check it in the documents tab. I would have thought it was like  c.na05.content.force.com

```
<img src=”https://c.na05.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01570000001G1nR&oid=00D70000000XXXX” alt=”My test image” height=”179” width=”702“/>
```

Also, for use in an email out you probably need to specify that it is an externally available image. This is done on the document itself, as the picture shows:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Comment Doug B                             i got the image in EmailTemplate.But i receive the template in email it doesn't shows the image automatically after click the display images then only it shows.Is this any possible ways to shows the image automatically?

Comment: I believe this behaviour is controlled by the email client receiving the message. For example, if you use gmail and you receive an email containing inline images from someone, then you will get a message asking if you want to "show images" and you also have the option to "always show images from this sender". As a sender I don't think it's possible to force the recipient to accept the images. If you are working inside an organisation you may be able to get the sender whitelisted within your organisation.

Comment: That's a common protection in many mail clients to stop spammers and other malicious users of tracking the fact email was opened and read (because image will be downloaded from SF servers and count as "hit"). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug. If you want to display your images regardless of that you might have to add them as attachments & reference them in the template!